# Django: Dockerfile error with collectsatic

Tags: django, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy Django application with Docker and Jenkins.

I get the error

```
"msg": "Error building registry.docker.si/... - code: 1 message: The command '/bin/sh -c if [ ! -d ./static ]; then mkdir static; fi && ./manage.py collectstatic --no-input' returned a non-zero code: 1"
}
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-dev && apt-get install -y libldap2-dev && apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev && apt-get install -y libssl-dev && apt-get install -y sasl2-bin

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN chmod u+rwx manage.py

RUN if [ ! -d ./static ]; then mkdir static; fi && ./manage.py collectstatic --no-input

RUN chown -R 10000:10000 ./

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["sh", "./run-django.sh"]
```

My problem is that, with same dockerfile other Django project deploy without any problem...

Comment: I am not sure, I think the collectstatic command might throw error. Can you please try running it outside of the docker and see what might be the problem ?